# How to get Service Studio to automatically add a menu item when a new page is created by intelliwarp

Tags: outsystems

I'm on a eSpace that stopped automatically creating menu items when I drag a entity onto a flow.
What are the steps I can take to make Service Studio resume this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out what is necessary for [that magic to happen here](http://www.outsystems.com/help/servicestudio/8.0/default.htm#Web_User_Interface/About_Scaffolding_a_CRUD.htm): . Check the topic about menu entries. It will tell that you need to have the menu set in the theme. You'll also need to have static entities for MenuItem and MenuSutItem - this last one is not mandatory.

Menu items are only automatically created for the list screens. You need to have a Menu web block defined for the theme and it needs to comply [with some rules described here](http://www.outsystems.com/help/servicestudio/8.0/User_Interface/Design_Screen_Layouts.htm#Design_Menu_Layout)

I hope this helps you.